# Newbie questions: real-time clustering of messages

Tags: nlp, clustering, text-classification, beginner, data-stream-mining

I'm very much a newbie in NLP, so please accept my apologies if this is an obvious question, the wrong place to ask it or any other error I could be making.

I am considering using NLP for some subset of real-time spam detection in real-time chat. The general idea would be to observe semantic clusters forming in real-time, as they *could* indicate activation of a wave of spambots. This, by itself, won't be sufficient to indicate that it's spam but I suspect that it would be an interesting data point in the process.

More specifically:

- my system receives text messages in real-time (e.g. thousands to tens of thousands per second);
- I would like to classify them and see if semantic clusters emerge;
- I will need to cleanup the data regularly (e.g. remove everything that's older than one hour) to avoid retaining potential private data;
- I cannot rely on external services for privacy reasons, so whatever happens, I'll need to write code. I'm fine with that.

I figure that I need to encode my text messages into vectors, using e.g. BERT or some other existing model. So far, so good. My difficulties are:

- real-time classification of a growing dataset, with an unknown number of clusters (I'll be able to experiment with the distance, though);
- regular cleanup.

Are there any well-known algorithms or libraries that I should look at? I'm not afraid to code and optimize my code, if I have a good reason to believe that it's going to work.

Answer (score 2):

This looks like a problem of [topic modelling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topic_model): unsupervised clustering based distributional semantics.

- For the issue of the unknown number of clusters, [HDP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hierarchical_Dirichlet_process) is certainly a good option.
- For analyzing the changing behaviour, there are *dynamic* topic models which can represent this, in particular [D-LDA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_topic_model), [DETM](https://arxiv.org/abs/1907.05545).